# Calling Objective-C methods in Swift closure causes memory leaks

Tags: swift, objective-c, memory-leaks, closures, automatic-ref-counting

I'm developing an IOS app where both Swift and Objective-C are needed. I find that calling Objective-C methods in Swift closures can cause memory leaks—An instance that is accessed in Objective-C methods will still be retained in memory even if nobody else references it.

Let's say that we have two classes `A` and `B`:

```
@objc class A : NSObject {
    @objc var name : String
    init(name : String) {
        self.name = name
        print("Class A \"\(self.name)\" is constructed.")
        super.init()
    }
    deinit {
        print("Class A \"\(self.name)\" is destructed.")
    }
}

@objc class B : NSObject {
    @objc var nestedClass : A
    init(nestedClass : A) {
        self.nestedClass = nestedClass
        print("Class B \"\(self.nestedClass.name)\" is constructed.")
        super.init()
    }
    deinit {
        print("Class B \"\(self. nestedClass.name)\" is destructed.")
    }
}
```

In our `ContentViewModel` class and in `startWorking` method, we keep instantiating class `B` in a closure:

```
class ContentViewModel : ObservableObject {
    
    private var _isWorking = ManagedAtomic<Bool>(false)
    private(set) var isWorking: Bool {
        set {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
            self._isWorking.store(newValue, ordering: .relaxed)
        }
        get {
            return self._isWorking.load(ordering: .relaxed)
        }
    }
    
    //To perform async work
    let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "ContentViewModel", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: .concurrent)
    
    //Objective-C interface, used to call objc methods
    let objcInterface = ObjcInterface()
    
    //Start
    func startWorking() {
        self.isWorking = true
        var count = 0
        self.dispatchQueue.async {
            while self.isWorking {
                //Instantiate class A and B
                let b = B(nestedClass: A(name: String(count)))
                //In "process" method, we do nothing but access "b.nestedClass". We do not retain it.
                self.objcInterface.process(b)
                count += 1
                //Now, "b" is no longer referenced. So, it should be destructed.
                //Also, its nested instance "b.nestedClass" should also be destructed.
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Stop
    func stopWorking() {
        self.isWorking = false
    }
}
```

In `process` method of `ObjcInterface` class, we do nothing but access `b.nestedClass`:

```objectivec
@implementation ObjcInterface
- (void)process:(B* _Nonnull)b {
    b.nestedClass;
}
@end
```

If we call `startWorking` method of `ContentViewModel` class (by the button in UI, for example), we expect that class `A` and `B` are kept constructed and destructed. However, if we look at the console:

```
Class A "0" is constructed.
Class B "0" is constructed.
Class B "0" is destructed.
Class A "1" is constructed.
Class B "1" is constructed.
Class B "1" is destructed.
Class A "2" is constructed.
Class B "2" is constructed.
Class B "2" is destructed.
Class A "3" is constructed.
Class B "3" is constructed.
Class B "3" is destructed.
Class A "4" is constructed.
Class B "4" is constructed.
Class B "4" is destructed.
Class A "5" is constructed.
Class B "5" is constructed.
Class B "5" is destructed.
Class A "6" is constructed.
Class B "6" is constructed.
Class B "6" is destructed.
......
```

We will find that class `A` is never destructed.

If we call method `stopWorking` of `ContentViewModel` class, where we notify the dispatch queue to finish executing the closure, all these instances of class `A` will be destructed:

```
......
Class A "7" is destructed.
Class A "6" is destructed.
Class A "5" is destructed.
Class A "4" is destructed.
Class A "3" is destructed.
Class A "2" is destructed.
Class A "1" is destructed.
Class A "0" is destructed.
```

This is not what I want to see. I want these instances of class `A` to be destructed as long as nobody else references them. Is this a bug of Clang's ARC implementation? Is there any elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you wrap the body of your while loop with  autoreleasepool { ... }

Comment: Running this code in isolation (without any frameworks but `Foundation` and `Atomics` imported) doesn't cause any leaks (`A` instances get deallocated at the end of the `while` loop). I believe @Shadowrun is right about using autorelease pools, as `A` instance might have instantiated with autorelease mechanism and as long as the GCD a pool of never-ending threads keep running, the `A` instances never leave autorelease pool they were instantiated in, so you may want to make your own